# WIX Setup - API call fails

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to make an API call inside WIX Installation SETUP Custom Action.

This is my API call (API is hosted on Azure)

```
    public LoginResult Authenticate(LoginResult model)
    {
        LoginResult loginResult = new LoginResult();

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(https ://xxx.com/api/authenticate);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {

            string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            streamWriter.Write(json);

        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var res = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            loginResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResult>(res);
        }

        return loginResult;
    }
```

Product.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="MSPmate Agent" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="MSPmate" UpgradeCode="2a2faae2-115e-4b45-aeeb-422663a2e357">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of MSPmate agent is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WixSetUpProject" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="CustomActionFormId" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
  </Product>
  <Fragment>
    <Binary Id="CustomActionBinary" SourceFile="$(var.WixCustomForms.TargetDir)$(var.WixCustomForms.TargetName).CA.dll" />
    <CustomAction Id="CustomActionFormId" Execute="immediate" Impersonate="no" BinaryKey="CustomActionBinary" DllEntry="PerformAuthentication" Return="check" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="MSPMATEAGENT" Name="WixSetUpProject" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="MSPMATEAGENT">
      <Component Id="ProductComponent">
        <File Source="$(var.RMMSetUp.TargetPath)" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I have tested the API method in a normal C# application it work but doesn't work when running inside a CustomAction on WIX setup.

Throws the exception

> underlying connection was closed unexpected error on send

Is there any specific setting I need to set on wxs file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Adding the security protocol fixed the issue for me.

```
public LoginResult Authenticate(LoginResult model)
        {
            LoginResult loginResult = new LoginResult();

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Constants.UserAuthentication);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {

                string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
                streamWriter.Write(json);

            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var res = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                loginResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResult>(res);
            }

            return loginResult;
        }
```